# customized json format for java language in play framework

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

In play framework, I can not find any documents for customized JSON structure in Java?  All docs are for scala....
For customizing:

Player.java

```
public class Player {
    Player (string f, string l, string age) {
        this.FirstName = f;
        this.LastName = l;
        this.Age = age;
    }
    public String FirstName ;
    public String LastName ;
    public String Age;
};
```

And run

```
list = conn.createQuery(sql);//sql has been created, and list is a list of Player
```

Now I have (this sturcture I get is from sqlite)

```
Player：[
{
    FirstName : AAA
    LastName : BBB
    Age : 20
}]
```

I want to change to

```
Player: [
{
    Name : {
       FirstName : AAA
       LastName :BBB
    }
    Age : 20
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What "custom JSON format"? JSON is JSON...

Comment: What's _customized JSON format_?

Comment: @fge I have edited my question again

Comment: @biesior  i have edited my question again

Comment: This doesn't change format, but it changes structure of JSON.

Comment: So show us how did you create the first version, that you don't want

Comment: is it clear? @biesior

Answer (score 0):

in very generic, when you're using Play's `toJson(...)` method:

- `List<Object>` will be converted to JSON array
- `Map<String, Object>` will be converted to JSON object
- You can use any combination of these (array of objects, object with arrays, etc)

(according to JSON spec: http://json.org/)

You need just fix your Player class... to fit these rules.

Comment: hi @biesior, could you be specific how could I change the player class... I am still a little confusing...